# Will a C union of uint32_t and uint8_t[4] will always map the same way on little endian architectures?

Tags: c, endianness

Will a C union of uint32_t and uint8_t[4] will always map the same way on little endian architectures?

e.g. with

```
union {
    uint32_t double_word;
    uint8_t octets[4];
} u;
```

will

```
u.double_word = 0x12345678;
```

always result in:

```
u.octets[0] == 0x78
u.octets[1] == 0x56
u.octets[2] == 0x34
u.octets[3] == 0x12
```

or is this undefined behaviour?

Comment: This is how endianness is defined. If you are on big endian, the byte array will be reversed

Comment: Yes, it's true *by definition*. What it means for a system to be "little endian" is that this relationship holds. The union behavior was historically undefined in C, but later defined as the result of a DR. Using it does have some caveats but you can always do the same safely with memcpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes, the code is fine.

As noted, it contains implementation-defined behavior depending on endianess, but other than that, the behavior is well-defined and the code is portable (between little endian machines).

---

**Detailed answer:**

One thing that's important is that the order of allocation of an array is guaranteed, C11 6.2.5/20:

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.

This means that the array of 4 `uint8_t` is guaranteed to follow the allocation order of the `uint32_t`, which on a little endian system means least significant byte first.

In theory, the compiler is however free to toss in any padding at the end of a union (C11 6.7.2.1/17), but that shouldn't affect the data representation. If you want to pedantically protect against this - or more relevantly, you wish to protect against an issue in case more members are added later - you can add a compile-time assert:

```
typedef union {
    uint32_t double_word;
    uint8_t octets[4];
} u;

_Static_assert(sizeof(u) == sizeof(uint32_t), "union u: Padding detected");
```

As for the representation of the `uintn_t` types, it is guaranteed to be 2's complement (in case of signed types) with no padding bits (C11 7.20.1.1).

And finally, the issue about whether "type punning" through a union is allowed or undefined behavior, this is specified a bit vaguely in C11 6.5.2.3:

> A postfix expression followed by the `.` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member,<sup>95)</sup> and is an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue.

Where the (non-normative) note 95 provides clarification:

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
>   store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
>   as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
>   punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

And since we already ruled out padding bits, trap representations is not an issue.

Comment: @chux Oh, struct or union. You are right, this is a bit confusing to read. I'll edit!

Comment: Fixed. It should make more sense now.

Comment: I didn't realize the fixed size types guaranteed two's complement.  That guarantee doesn't exist for other integer types.  That could make for some very interesting conversions between `int` and `int32_t` for example.

Comment: @dbush the guarantee about `intN_t` being 2's complement also comes with the loophole that they are _optional_ types if the platform does not readily support them.  When an `int` is not 2's complement, it is unlikely that `int32_t` exists , thus negated the [very interesting conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627802/will-a-c-union-of-uint32-t-and-uint8-t4-will-always-map-the-same-way-on-little/49628541?noredirect=1#comment86271575_49628541).

Answer (score 3):

On a platform that actually *has* both of these types, C11 **§7.20.1.1 p2** gives you all the needed guarantees (given you know endianness):

> The typedef name `uintN_t` designates an unsigned integer type with width *N* and no
>   padding bits. Thus, `uint24_t` denotes such an unsigned integer type with a width of
>   exactly 24 bits.

This is enough because there are no bytes with fewer than 8 bits, so having `uint8_t` available automatically means that a byte has exactly 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted to make sure that "accessing the value of a union, by a field other than that through which it was set" was allowed by standards rather than just common practise.

Comment: @fadedbee It's allowed in C and undefined behavior in C++. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior.